# JS change imported initialization param after

Tags: javascript

This may be a stupid question... but... if I have something like this in JavaScript:

```
const thing = require('somelib');

const test = thing({
  param1: 'value1',
  param2: 'value2,
  param3: 'value3'
});
```

...and later I want to change `thing`'s `param2` value to `'value9'` or something - can that be done with full re-declaration and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends only on `somelib` implementation and design.

If it has some sort of `test.set("param2", newValue)` method or simply exposes `test.param2` property outside, then you can change it.
If developers did not make it possible by design, then you need to redeclare your `thing`.